# Android Studio Package 2.2 RC2 Structure

Tags: java, android, package, kotlin

I've a problem with Android Studio 2.2 RC2, when I add a new package into project structure I don't see the standard:

```
app
  +-- java
      +-- com.myapp
          +-- package
```

but this:

```
app
  +-- java
      +-- com.myapp
          +-- com.myapp.package
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Where did you click and what did you then type when saying "New Package?"

Answer (score 0):

One possible scenario:

When you add a new package in Intellij (any version including Android studio), the command operates based on the context of where you right-clicked to select `New -> Package`.  Think of `New -> Package` as really meaning `New -> Add subpackage at this point in three`.

So you right-click at the source root of `app/java` and select `New -> Package` and type `one.two.three` you end up with:

```
app
  +-- java
      +-- one
          +-- two
              +-- three
```

But if you right-click on the new node in the project tree of `app/java/one/two/three` and select `New -> Package` typing `one.two.other` you end up nesting the package within the other.  Your tree would then be:

```
app
  +-- java
      +-- one
          +-- two
              +-- three
                  +-- one             <---- OOOPS!
                      +-- two
                          +-- other
```

But had I right clicked back at the root of `app/java` and typed the same package name `one.two.other` I would have ended up with:

```
app
  +-- java
      +-- one
          +-- two
              +-- three
              +-- other
```

I could also click on the tree at `app/one/two` a typed only `other` to get the same, again because `New -> Package` is adding a sub package to where I happen to have taken the action.

Just because you type what appears to be a fully qualified package name in `New -> Package` doesn't mean that Intellij knows you mean to go back and start at the root.  It nests from wherever you clicked even if it may be obvious (*to you*) what you intended, Intellij consistently does the action from where you started the action.

Some screenshots of this in action...

**Adding at the wrong place:** (notice the selection in the project tree)

[image: Adding package at the wrong place]

Results in:

[image: Result of adding package at the wrong place]

**Adding at the correct place:**  (notice the selection in the project tree)

[image: Adding package at the correct place]

Results in:

[image: Result of adding package at the correct place]

**Also adding at the correct place:**  (expand collapsed middle packages to see as tree)

[image: Adding package at the correct place]

Results in:

[image: Result of adding package at the correct place]

Comment: The problem is not package creation, but the tree structure view. I don't see `other` or `three` but `one.two.other` and `one.two.three`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:
If add

> ```
> dataBinding {
>     enabled = true
> }
> ```

to app .gradle the project structure is displayed without standard children.

Comment: what led you to that conclusion?  is it documented somewhere (its relationship to what you saw in the project tree)?

Comment: I've tested it and I see that some packages are not grouped